# runnig a function when leave each li tag but mouse out is defined in the ul tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `ul` tag that has an `onmouseout` function.
The `ul` contains 4 `li` elements.
I want a function to be called when I leave the `ul`, but it is called when I go from one `li` to another `li`.
Where is my mistake?

My list is:

```
<ul id="settings" style="position:fixed;" onmouseout="alert(20);">
<li><a href="#">111</a></li>
<li><a href="#">222</a></li>
<li><a href="#">333</a></li>
<li><a href="#">444</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Add `overflow: hidden` to the `ul` or use a clearfix, see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Handling `onmouseout` on `ul` is a bit tricky, yes. You need to take care of [event bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616694/2454376) since `onmouseout` can fire on `a` or `li` and propagate back to `ul`. So even when you're leaving children elements - event will be fired for `ul` unless propagation is explicitly prevented.

Since you have jQuery tag, I can suggest this clean & easy approach:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mMbWS/)

HTML:

```
<ul id="settings" style="position:fixed;">
    <li><a href="#">111</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">222</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">333</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">444</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$("#settings").mouseleave(function() {
    // Better to debug with console.log()
    // alert(20); 
    console.log(20);
});
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? Do you have browser console opened? Also, try uncommenting `alert(20)` line.